# Twitter Bootstrap classes(grids, navs) not rendering

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

So I have twitter bootstrap response in my app assets stylesheets, and it shows in the head of the document from Google Chrome's dev tools like so:

```
<link href="/assets/bootstrap-responsive.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Yet when I use classes to try and make bootstrap buttons, use the grid system or the built-in nav, nothing happens.  For instance, Here's how I tried to the gride system to work.

```
%h1 Your Polls

.dashboard-wrapper.row
  .user-polls.span6
    %h1 test

  .create-polls.span6
    = link_to 'Create New Poll', new_poll_path, remote: true
```

With this CSS:

```
.dashboard-wrapper{
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.user-polls {

}

.create-polls{

}
```

Any ideas on why it might not be working?
  Thanks!!

Comment: Is that CSS file accessible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bootstrap-responsive.css` is a small file containing responsive (phone/tablet) tweaks for the main `bootstrap.css` file. Did you include the main `bootstrap.css` file?